# Is Model-View-Controller Poor Object-Oriented Design?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, language-agnostic

Both OOD (Object-Oriented-Design) and MVC (Model-View-Controller) architectures have become staples of modern software design.  Yet, I have recently had an interesting discussion regarding how MVC architectures utilize (and possilby even *violate*) OOD principles.  This possibility is actually rather intriguing since both OOD and MVC are intended to achieve many of the same goals: separation-of-concerns and software re-usability.  But the question I pose: **Are these two design strategies in direct conflict with each-other?**  As I have used both, in practice, I am beginning to think: quite possibly yes.

I say so because: Enforcing a strict separate between models, views and controllers often results in architectures where models are implemented as dumb *containers* that can only be manipulated via external controllers.  I argue this directly conflicts one of the chief principles of object-oriented design: where objects contain operations that perform necessary operations and encapsulate them as necessary.  For example, in a pure Object-Oriented architecture a hypothetical `File` class would contain methods such as `open()` and `save()`.  MVC suggests that we have two classes `File` and `FileManager` (such that the later contains the `open()` and `save()` methods).  To me: the MVC design is rather messy.  If ones needs to create a more specialized type of `File` (say for handling Files that stream across a network on `open()` or `save()`), one only needs to sub-class `File` with a class called (let's say): `StreamedFile`.  With MVC, you'd have to either create another manager class or complicate the design of the original manager class.

From this, **it follows that in a more complex system MVC could have disastrous effects on both separation of concerns and code re-usability.  Or Not?  Perhaps MVC patterns could be implemented without breaking OOD principles?  Or Is MVC an inherently flawed approach that makes it difficult to implement software systems with loosely coupled components?**

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168316/isnt-mvc-anti-oop

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the contrary, healthy MVC use should encourage *skinny* controllers and *fat* models, so that the models (the objects) is where the action happens (which itself encourages encapsulation and other good OOP principles), and the controllers are merely there to point certain requests in the right direction to the objects.

Comment: And OOD discourages skinny and fat classes. It encourages distribution of weight (and food) between its first class citizens (objects).

Answer (score 5):

Nothing in MVC says that `Model` should be stupid (anemic model). I think it is completely appropriate to have rich `Model` classes, which eliminate the need of 'managers'.

That being said, it is currently popular practice to use `ViewModel`s for passing data to a `View`. `ViewModel` is basically a projection of your `Model` tailored specifically for a particular `View`. It can be regarded as `Model` from `View`'s perspective, a facade for a rich `Model`; so of course there is much more to a `Model` than just `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not call MVC an architecture that is on the same pain as OOD. MVC is just an OOD pattern that can be applied in certain designs. Thus it simple does not compete with OOD and it’s just one of your tools to build a good or bad OOD design. Just like a hammer does not compete with good wood craftsmanship, the hammer, like MVC, is just a tool in the craftsman’s toolbox.

It neither is pattern that facilitates bad design. Because a good OOD design will have a good separation of concerns, the MVC pattern can provide that for you by separating the presentation concerns (view) from the application logic (controller) and the more fundamental domain logic (model). As such it’s a good OO pattern that is often applied in user interfaces. But there are other competing patterns that could also be considered while making a good OOD.

Answer (score 1):

We have two forms of MVC, Pull MVC and Push MVC (aka Component Based MVC and Legacy MVC).

Push MVC focuses on separation of concepts, each model-view-controller set handles some aspect of the application and can be engineered and developed by some separate people. When the system is rapidly developing, it works great, and adding features is easy too. Code re-use in larger systems gets terrible. Essentially only models are re-used.

Pull MVC, focuses on code re-use via using widgets (components of view), so that many views share the same code and only customize their widgets. As for controllers, common controller practices are abstracted and performed.

It is a matter of mixing Pull and Push MVCs depending on the nature and pace of the software.

Comment: Very interesting.  Personally, I'm torn as to whether I would describe both forms of MVC as "push" or "pull" since the destinction you are making is more about the distribution of code reusability across the view/model boundary and less about which side of the application has more control over execution-flow.  On the other hand: This phenomenon of implementing models with careful attention to OOD, while quickly slapping together views has been common practice.  And with much of application intelligence moving towards the client-side, I see what you describe as "pull MVC" gaining momentum.

Comment: I believe controllers should be routers. Routers keyword is used in javascript mvc frameworks and even java spring controllers are supposed to be routers plus data binders. But in conventional MVC style a centralized models, centralized controllers and centralized views are a pain to look up and time waste in switching context during thinking and coding. I believe MVC's time is over, component/widget based frameworks are more welcome.